# Using certificate in ftp connector Azure Logic apps

Tags: azure, ftp, certificate, sftp, azure-logic-apps

Hi i was wondering a little bit about how the FTP connector in Logic Apps in Azure make use of the certificate from a sftp server.

In azure i can see a box where i can specify true or false depending if i want to use a certificate or not but how does the connector use it and where does it store the certificate?

[image]

In short: How does this work related to a FTP connector in Azure?

Comment: FTP and SFTP are two completely different protocols. SFTP doesn't use certificates. That dialog looks like it's for FTP(S) (FTP with encryption), not SFTP.

Comment: I understand, i may have miss understood that, i'll take a look at the difference and then be back for an edit. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently supported. Please upvote on uservoice if you want to be able to use a cert instead of username/password combo for SFTP connection.

As a workaround in the meantime you can use a custom trigger/action to get up and running. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-logic/app-service-logic-create-api-app and samples at: https://github.com/logicappsio

Comment: I'm happy you understood what i ment, and thank you for the answer!